# Azure Development newb

Tags: 2013, azure, source-control, visual-studio-online

Our team is exploring development environments in Azure and I was hoping to get some clarity on the actual setup. We currently all have stand alone dev machines (team of 5).

1)To continue developing farm solutions in the cloud, do we need VS 2013 on our Azure machines or can it all be done with Visual Studio Online?

2)What would you suggest for source control? Is it just TFVC available through VS Online when using Azure?

3) Can developers share dev machines in Azure, or should we each have our own tied to a separate SQL instance?

Thanks for the insight

Answer (score 1):

1) Didn't work with Visual Studio **Online**, but I don't see any differencies between Your 'real' dev machines and Azure. You can use what You want like on a standalone machine too

2) I use TFS online http://tfs.visualstudio.com in azure vms. Will be free if team is up to 5

3) All like in real life, You can put Your machines in one network and share SQL instance for others. Or I'd prefer to use standalone installation for developer VM..